# Mover commit de un proyecto a otro proyecto

Tags: git

¿Cómo se puede mover un commit especifico a otro proyecto?

Actualmente tengo dos proyectos en GitLab, se realizo un desarrollo largo en un proyecto. Mi objetivo es mover dicho desarrollo o commit a otro proyecto debido a que los proyectos tienen el mismo código pero son destinados para diferentes plataformas.

¿Es posible?

Comment: Una forma podría ser agregando otro `git remote`, pero tendrías que lidiar con posibles conflictos en el `merge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Exportar en un `gzip` los archivos modificados en dicho `commit`

  ```
  $ git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT [COMMIT_ID] | tar -czf files.tgz -T -
  # Reemplazar [COMMIT_ID] por el hash
  ```
- Y luego extraes el contenido del archivo `gzip` en el otro proyecto

  ```
  $ tar -zxf files.tgz -C [PROJECT_PATH]
  # Reemplazar [PROJECT_PATH] por la ruta completa al directorio del proyecto
  ```